# Input onChanged value not set in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using ReactHooks UseState and wanted to set value in useState but its not working.. why?? help me??

**JS**

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({
  headline: '',
  paragraph: '',
});

const onChanged = (e) => {
  let { name, value } = e.target.value;
  setValue((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
};
```

**HTML**

```html
<input
  value="{value.headline}"
  onChange="{onChanged}"
  type="text"
  name="headline"
/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should do `let {name, value} = e.target`, remove the `.value` from the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will work...

```
const {name, value} = e.target
setValue(prev => ({...prev, [name]: value}))
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your destructuring:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    headline: '',
    paragraph: ''
});

const onChanged = e => {
    let {name, value} = e.target // <--- You do not need .value here
    setValue(prev => ({...prev, [name]: value}))
}

 <input
   value={value.headline}
   onChange={onChanged}
   type="text" name="headline" />
```

You are desrturing from `value` so `e.target.value` is wrong.